# Why `git config -f`command doesn't work with a file of network folder for me?

Tags: git

Git for Windows 2.4.5.
It works fine with a local config-file:

```
git config -f "d:\\dev\\settings\\gitconfig.txt" http.proxy http://@proxy2:8080
```

I need to do the same with a config-file which is located at the network in our domain. This config-file is common for all developers of our company and has common settings (the proxy settings, for example). I have full rights for working with that directory. I launch this:

```
git config -f "\\\\hyprostr\\dfs\\groups\\developers\\settings\\gitconfig.txt" http.proxy http://@proxy2:8080
```

But it doesn't work. I see the message:

[image]

if I press `y` then I get the same message again...

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

**UPD**

This works fine:

```
echo 123 > "\\\\hyprostr\\dfs\\groups\\developers\\settings\\gitconfig.txt"
```

and this works fine too:

```
mv "\\\\hyprostr\\dfs\\groups\\developers\\settings\\gitconfig.txt" "\\\\hyprostr\\dfs\\groups\\developers\\settings\\gitconfig2.txt"
```

So, I don't understand the reason of the problem...

Comment: try `//hyprostr/dfs/groups/` instead.

Comment: @eckes, I got the same problem for the command: `git config -f "//hyprostr/dfs/groups/developers/settings/gitconfig.txt" http.proxy http://@proxy2:8080`

Comment: just tried it (2.4.4.windows.2). Works fine for me.  Must be a rights issue.

Comment: I have full rights. Through Windows Explorer I create, edit, remove and rename files and directories without problems in this location.

Comment: This works fine (from Git Bash): ` echo 123 > "\\\\hyprostr\\dfs\\groups\\developers\\settings\\gitconfig.txt"`

Comment: Could it be the case that the remote `gitconfig.txt` is opened by another program? If you're unsure: check with the ProcessExplorer of the SysInternals suite.

Comment: No, this is my directory only. It was created special for me by admin (an hour ago) and only I have full access to it.

Comment: I added `UPD` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519051/git-for-windows-doesnt-work-correctly-with-network-directories)) problems were fixed in the Git for Windows 2.5.2 (thank you, [Vonc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)):

> Many bugs have been fixed with the mingw-64 bash on top of which git
>   for windows is based.