# Git for Windows doesn't work correctly with network directories

Tags: windows, git

I use [Git for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385707/why-git-config-fcommand-doesnt-work-with-a-file-of-network-folder-for-me) I wrote about the `git config -f ...` problem.

But I get the same problem for other commands too:

```
$ git init --bare //hyprostr/dfs/groups/developers/src/GitCribs
Rename from '//hyprostr/dfs/groups/developers/src/GitCribs/config.lock' to '//hyprostr/dfs/groups/developers/src/GitCribs/config' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

Pressing `y` or `n` key doesn't help. Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you still using 2.4.5? Or the latest 2.5.2?

Comment: Can you check first if the issue persists in 2.5.2? No setup required, just unzip the archive '`PortableGit-2.5.2-64-bit.7z.exe`'. (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.2-64-bit.7z.exe)

Comment: I've unzipped this and launched the `git-bash.exe`. For first launching I got many errors in the output. I delete unzipped folder and did the same again. Now I hadn't the errors. I see, my command works successfully in the `2.5.2`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Git 2.5.2 ([`PortableGit-2.5.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.2-64-bit.7z.exe)):

Many bugs have been fixed with the mingw-64 bash on top of which git for windows is based.